# unexpected T_Variable error, what is causing it in loop?

Tags: php

I ma receiving an error stating:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in .... on line 599

which belongs in the line below:

```
foreach ($questions as $key=>$question) {

    echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_num'][$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_content']$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;

    }
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Below is code:

```
    $question = array();

    while ($selectedstudentanswerstmt->fetch()) {

    $row_question = array();
    $row_question['question_num'] = $detailsQuestionNo;
    $row_question['question_content'] = $detailsQuestionContent;
    $row_question['question_option'] = $detailsOptionType;
    $row_question['question_num_answers'] = $detailsNoofAnswers;
    $row_question['question_answer'] = $detailsAnswer;
    $row_question['questionnum_reply'] = $detailsReplyType;
    $row_question['questionnum_marks'] = $detailsQuestionMarks;
    $questions[] = $row_question;
}

.................

<?php   

          foreach ($questions as $key=>$question) {

echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_num'][$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_content']$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;

}
?>
```

Comment: `$row_question['question_content']$key]` should be`$row_question['question_content'][$key]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a bracket

```
    echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_num'][$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_content']$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
```

should be

```
    echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong> ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_num'][$key]). ': ' .htmlspecialchars($row_question['question_content'][$key]). '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Oh god sorry bout, that best answer, can I quickly ask a little question, when I fix bracket, it outputs just the first letter of question content and no question_num, is the fixed line correct in displaying the info from the array?